# Cairo compiling error: undefined reference

Tags: c, reference, undefined, cairo

I begin learning about cairo for C, I previously installed the cairo library (libcairo2-dev) and I have the folder cairo in /usr/include.
I tried to compile this in every way (also using pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo) and the static linking but nothing:

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

int main(void)
{
  cairo_surface_t *surface;
  cairo_t *cr;

  surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 390, 60);
  cr = cairo_create(surface);

  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
      CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
  cairo_set_font_size(cr, 50.0);

  cairo_move_to(cr, 10.0, 50.0);
  cairo_show_text(cr, "Hi at all");

  cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

  cairo_destroy(cr);
  cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

  return 0;
}
```

the compiling error is:

```
cairo.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `cairo_image_surface_create'
cairo.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `cairo_create'
cairo.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `cairo_set_source_rgb'
cairo.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `cairo_select_font_face'
cairo.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `cairo_set_font_size'
cairo.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `cairo_move_to'
cairo.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `cairo_show_text'
cairo.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_write_to_png'
cairo.c:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `cairo_destroy'
cairo.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Its obvious that you're not linking your library properly. What is the command you are using to compile?

Comment: I tried gcc -o cairo cairo.c; gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo` -o cairo cairo.c; gcc -o cairo cairo.c `pkg-config --cflags cairo` -static `pkg-config --libs cairo`